# Method or event which close telegram web app

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I make telegram web app using React Js.
I need method which closed telegram web app and returned to chat.
I found info that there is method close in **window.Telegram.WebApp**. But it's undefined when I consoled. And this method doesn't work.
Even console.log(window) return nothing in telegram web app

Answer (score 1):

To make Telegram object appear in global `window` object, you have to append Telegram's script in your `<head/>` tag. You can find official mention about it [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#initializing-web-apps).

Nevertheless, I don't recommend usage of Telegram's script as long as its code is recognized as not optimal and probably vulnerable. To avoid known problems, you can use up-to-date TypeScript libraries, such as [`twa-sdk`](https://telegram-web-apps.github.io/twa/docs/libraries/twa-sdk/about) or [`twa-bridge`](https://telegram-web-apps.github.io/twa/docs/libraries/twa-bridge).

Comment: "probably vulnerable" Do you have a source for this so I can study about it. Making a web app now and don't want to introduce vulnerabilities.

Comment: @OrbitingEden you can find included Telegram script in their official [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#initializing-web-apps). The most important spots there are connected with parent window communication without checking its origin (window.parent.postMessage(..., '*')) and usage of session storage, which does not really work in Web Apps (works in web version only). As the result, your application will not check data receiver origin, which allows the attacker to insert iframe with your application. Its "probably vulnerable" as long as it could probably be used in future.

Comment: I have reviewed the code around lines 20-47 of https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js and it seems to be handling communication between an already established iframe and the parent window. The only way I could envision this being a vulnerability is if a third party created an iframe running your webapp bot, but to do that they would need to have control over your buttons in the Telegram app. Or am I missing something?

Comment: As attacker, you could insert Web App iframe into your own Web App. Inserted Web App does not check its parent origin and always trust it. It means, attacker could send any message to inserted iframe and application will not reject it. Then we could dive deeper into how sent message is processed by Telegram library. The first worrying thing  is on line 36 - possible XSS, but, luckily, <style> tag is safe to update inner HTML. The second thing is on line 142 where trusted target is any. Developers left uncommented dev line 141,  So, attacker will keep getting events in case app sends them.

Comment: You can try interesting case by yourself. Create web app with `<body>` tag containing `iframe` with src set to https://walletbot.me/wv?staticVersion=0_0_324 (actual @wallet Web App source). Then, go to @wallet app in web version of Telegram, close application. In the same tab open your own Web App with previously specified iframe. You will see working wallet in different Web App. The reason is, wallet loaded data from session storage. Summing up with not checking parent iframe, it is hard to imagine what can happen then. App is continuously developing and could accidently open vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in global params in TS
Need to declare

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    Telegram: {
      WebApp: {
        close: () => void;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
Telegram.WebApp.MainButton
        .setText('CLOSE WEBVIEW')
        .show()
        .onClick(function(){ webviewClose(); });
</script>
```

---

```
<div id="buttons" style="margin-top:100px;">          
<button onclick="webviewClose();">Close</button>
</div>
```